QGIS Label Placement Engine Ignoring Straight Lines
I've been digging into the label placement engine in the new QGIS version (3.38.2-Grenoble) and it's doing something odd: It doesn't seem to even suggest candidates on certain parts of line strings, even straight ones where label placement would be ideal.
Here's an example: I have a MultiLineString layer which I am hoping to label with periodically repeating labels. I've got into the placement engine settings and checked "show all labels for all layers", "show unplaced labels", and "show candidates (for debugging)" in order to understand what exactly is going on. It's currently set to "curved" label placement but the same thing happens with the other options.
I've noticed that quite suddenly QGIS isn't even suggesting candidate locations at all, despite the very straight sections of lines that are shown in the image below.

I have tried all the other permutations of priority, removing collisions, etc. If I force it to label each sub feature it does, but obviously I don't want to label each one, I would just like more candidate locations so the resulting label spacing makes sense.
Anyone have any insight as to why this behaviour is happening? Does it have something to do with the MultiLineString?
